# Difference between GClock and Clock Buffer Replacement Policies?

Tags: database, postgresql-9.1, framebuffer

What is the difference between GClock and Clock replacement policies?

Answer (score 1):

GENERALIZED CLOCK PAGE REPLACEMENT ALGORITHM.
With each page frame in memory we associate a count field and we arrange these count fields in a circular list. Whenever a page is referenced, the associated count field is set to i. When a page fault occurs, a pointer that circles around this circular list of page frames is observed. If the count field pointed to is zero, then the page is removed and the new page is placed in that frame. Otherwise, the count is
decremented by 1, the pointer is advanced to the next count field, and the process is repeated. When a new page is placed in the page frame, the count field is set to i if the page is to be referenced (demand fetch) and it is set to j if the page has been prepaged and is not immediately referenced. We abbreviate this algorithm by writing CLOCKP(j, i). The “P” indicates that this is a prepaging algorithm (the prepaging strategy has not been specified). When no prepaging is involved, the algorithm is abbreviated CLOCK(i) . The algorithm used in MULTICS and CP-67 is CLOCK(1).

[Sequentiality and prefetching in database systems](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320276)

So, CLOCK is GCLOCK(1).